# Change image color and drawable state dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable, colorfilter

I have few drawable logos and I need to change their colors dynamically. I'm getting two different color codes(one for normal state and other for pressed state) for the logos from server. Below is my method to color the logos and set drawable state dynamically.

```
private void changeColorDrawable(int drawableIconId, String normalStateColorCode, String pressedStateColorCode, ImageView icon) {

    Drawable state_normal = getResources().getDrawable(drawableIconId).mutate();
    state_normal.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF"+normalStateColorCode), Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    Drawable state_pressed = getResources().getDrawable(drawableIconId).mutate();
    state_pressed.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF"+pressedStateColorCode), Mode.SRC_ATOP);

    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},state_pressed);
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused, android.R.attr.state_enabled}, state_pressed);
    states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_enabled}, state_normal);

    icon.setImageDrawable(states);
}
```

I'm able to re-color the logos but unable to achieve the pressed state. 
How do I set the pressed state?

Comment: Can you ask a specific question? Your general request for help is too broad.

Comment: You want to change your `ImageView` state dynamically?

Comment: @joao2fast4u : Exactly